# Java Swing; how to show text after button is clicked

Tags: java, swing, text, jbutton

I want 'Hello world!' to show when my button is clicked. 
So go to a next 'frame' but in the same window!
I tried card lay-out, but can any one tell me how to do it with this code;

What am i doing wrong in this code?

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;



public class myTest{

public static void main(String[] args){

JPanel panel = new JPanel();

JButton button1 = new JButton();

frame.add(panel);
panel.add(button1);

  button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello World");

            }
        });

}

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try with code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class myTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JButton button1 = new JButton();

        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(button1);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame.getComponent(0), "Hello World");

            }
        });

    }

}
```

It is working as expected.

OR if you want the message to be on the same Frame then try with this code.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class myTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JButton button1 = new JButton();

        final JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World");

        label.setVisible(false);
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(button1);
        panel.add(label);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame.getComponent(0), "Hello World");
                label.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you it works exactly! But i meant in the same window! Sorry

Comment: of course, but i meant the text to appear in the same 'window'as the button like a next 'page'

Comment: @Opoe, I have given code for both the ways of displaying, check now.

Answer (score 1):

Change `frame.add(panel);` to `frame.getContentPane().add(panel);` also i assume that you have initialized the frame using `JFrame frame = new JFrame();`

Comment: thank you for your time well i'm a beginner and the above is my code, do i also have to add JFrame frame = new JFrame(); ?

Comment: Indeed you have to. The JFrame represents the Window. Without it, there's nothing to add the panel to. See @GuruKulki's Code it's working.

Comment: Thank you all, i explained it wrong, i want the Hello World to appear in the same window as the button. Like going to a next 'page'

Answer (score 0):

You should have given a better explanation about your problem, but reading your code I assume your problem is that you are not seeing anything when you run your program. Try to add the lines below in your code.

```
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```